# Delphi video streaming Http Server

Tags: delphi, video, streaming

How to implement following with Indy HTTP Server. The client accesses to http:// server_name:port, and the server returns it the video stream, which is stored at http:// server_name_video:port/video1.mpg

Comment: why you dont use Tembeddedwb instead of indy to achieve this purpose

Comment: TEmbeddedWB is a client-side browser. The OP wants to create a server instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TIdHTTPServer` does not natively support streaming media. You have to implement it manually.  In your `OnCommandGet` event handler, assign your desired values to the `AResponseInfo` parameter as needed, such as `ContentType` and `TransferEncoding`, and leave the `ContentText` and `ContentStream` properties unassigned, then call `AResponseInfo.WriteHeader()` to send just the response headers to the client, then enter a loop writing your video media data in chunks (according to the format described in [RFC 2616 Section 3.6.1 Chunked Transfer Coding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1)
) until the client disconnects or the end of the media is reached.  For example:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  FS: TFileStream;
  Buf: TIdBytes;
  BufLen: Integer;
begin
  if ARequestInfo.Document <> '/' then
  begin
    AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 404;
    Exit;
  end;
  FS := TFileStream.Create('video1.mpg', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
    AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'video/mpeg';
    AResponseInfo.TransferEncoding := 'chunked';
    AResponseInfo.WriteHeader;

    SetLength(Buf, 1024);
    repeat
      BufLen := FS.Read(Buf[0], 1024);
      if BufLen < 1 then Break;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(IntToHex(BufLen, 1));
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(Buf, BufLen);
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn;
    until False;

    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('0');
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn;
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

On the other hand, if you are trying to stream media from another server, it gets a bit more complicated.  You have to send a request to the other server, receive the response, and then forward the data to your client.  However, `TIdHTTP` does not support streaming media, so it would be difficult to use it for this purpose.  You will likely end up having to use `TIdTCPClient` directly instead and implement the necessary portions of the HTTP protocol yourself, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  Client: TIdTCPClient;
  Headers: TIdHeaderList;
  S, ResponseCode, ResponseText: string;
  Size: Int64;
  Strm: TIdTCPStream;    
begin
  if ARequestInfo.Document <> '/' then
  begin
    AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 404;
    Exit;
  end;
  Client := TIdTCPClient.Create;
  try
    Client.Host := 'server_name_video';
    Client.Port := port;
    Client.Connect;
    try
      Client.IOHandler.WriteLn('GET /video1.mpg HTTP/1.0');
      Client.IOHandler.WriteLn('Host: server_name_video');
      Client.IOHandler.WriteLn;

      ResponseText := Client.IOHandler.ReadLn;
      Fetch(ResponseText);
      ResponseText := TrimLeft(ResponseText);
      ResponseCode := Fetch(ResponseText, ' ', False);
      ResponseCode := Fetch(ResponseCode, '.', False);

      if ResponseCode <> '200' then
      begin
        AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := StrToInt(ResponseCode);
        AResponseInfo.ResponseText := ResponseText;
        Exit;
      end;

      Headers := TIdHeaderList.Create(QuoteHTTP);
      try
        Headers.FoldLength := MaxInt;

        repeat
          s := Client.IOHandler.ReadLn;
          if s = '' then Break;
          Headers.Add(s);
        until False;

        Strm := TIdTCPStream.Create(AContext.Connection);
        try
          AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
          AResponseInfo.ContentType := Headers.Values['Content-Type'];

          if Pos('chunked', Headers.Values['Transfer-Encoding']) <> 0 then
          begin
            AResponse.TransferEncoding := 'chunked';
            AResponseInfo.WriteHeader;

            repeat
              s := Client.IOHandler.ReadLn;
              AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(s);
              Size := StrToInt64('$'+Fetch(s, ';'));
              if Size = 0 then Break;
              Client.IOHandler.ReadStream(Strm, Size, False);
              s := Client.IOHandler.ReadLn;
              AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(s);
            until false;

            repeat
              s := Client.IOHandler.ReadLn;
              AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(s);
            until s = '';
          end
          else if Headers.IndexOfName('Content-Length') <> -1 then
          begin
            Size := StrToInt64(Headers.Values['Content-Length']);
            AResponseInfo.ContentLength := Size;
            AResponseInfo.WriteHeader;
            if Size > 0 then
              Client.IOHandler.ReadStream(Strm, Size, False);
          end else
          begin
            AResponseInfo.CloseConnection := true;
            AResponseInfo.WriteHeader;
            try
              Client.IOHandler.ReadStream(Strm, -1, True);
            except
              on E: EIdSocketError do begin
                if not (E.LastError in [10053, 10054, 10058]) then
                  raise;
              end;
            end;
          end;
        finally
          Strm.Free;
        end;
      finally
        Headers.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Client.Disconnect;
    end;
  finally
    Client.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Of course, if needed, you will have to also implement things like HTTP authentication, requests for byte ranges, etc.

**Update**: Or, rather than use `TIdTCPClient` directly, you could use `TIdHTTP` after all, just give it an output `TStream` that writes back to the original client as it is being written to.  You could use `TIdEventStream` for that purpose, or write your own `TStream` class, eg:

```
type
  TMyStream = class(TIdBaseStream)
  protected
    FHTTP: TIdHTTP;
    FClient: TIdIOHandler;
    FResponse: TIdHTTPResponseInfo;
    function IdRead(var VBuffer: TIdBytes; AOffset, ACount: Longint): Longint; override;
    function IdWrite(const ABuffer: TIdBytes; AOffset, ACount: Longint): Longint; override;
    function IdSeek(const AOffset: Int64; AOrigin: TSeekOrigin): Int64; override;
    procedure IdSetSize(ASize: Int64); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AHTTP: TIdHTTP; AClient: TIdIOHandler; AResponse: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TMyStream.Create(AHTTP: TIdHTTP; AClient: TIdIOHandler; AResponse: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FHTTP := AHTTP;
  FClient := AClient;
  FResponse := AResponse;
end;

destructor TMyStream.Destroy;
begin
  if FResponse.HeaderHasBeenWritten then
  begin
    FClient.WriteLn('0');
    FClient.WriteLn('');
  end;
end;

function TMyStream.IdRead(var VBuffer: TIdBytes; AOffset, ACount: Longint): Longint;
begin
  Result := 0;
end;

function TMyStream.IdWrite(const ABuffer: TIdBytes; AOffset, ACount: Longint): Longint;
begin
  if not FResponse.HeaderHasBeenWritten then
  begin
    FResponse.ResponseNo := 200;
    FResponseInfo.ContentType := FHTTP.Response.ContentType;
    FResponse.TransferEncoding := 'chunked';
    FResponse.WriteHeader;
  end;
  FClient.WriteLn(IntToHex(IndyLength(ABuffer, ACount, AOffset)));
  FClient.Write(ABuffer, ACount, AOffset);
  FClient.WriteLn;
end;

function TMyStream.IdSeek(const AOffset: Int64; AOrigin: TSeekOrigin): Int64;
begin
  Result := 0;
end;

procedure TMyStream.IdSetSize(ASize: Int64);
begin
end;

procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Strm: TMyStream;
begin
  if ARequestInfo.Document <> '/' then
  begin
    AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 404;
    Exit;
  end;
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    HTTP.HTTPOptions := HTTP.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException];
    Strm := TMyStream.Create(HTTP, AContext.Connection.IOHandler, AResponseInfo);
    try
      HTTP.Get('http://server_name_video:'+IntToStr(port)+'/video1.mpg', Strm);
    finally
      Strm.Free;
    end;
    if not AResponseInfo.HeaderHasBeenWritten then
    begin
      AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := HTTP.ResponseCode;
      AResponseInfo.ResponseText := HTTP.ResponseText;
    end;
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, if the other server supports `chunked` responses, you can either:

1. use the new `TIdHTTP.OnChunkReceived` event to write each received chunk to the client, similar to above without using a custom `TStream` (you still have to provide a `TStream` to `TIdHTTP.Get()`. You could use `TIdEventStream` for that, and just not assign any event handlers to it so data gets discarded. This may change in the future).
2. enable `TIdHTTP`'s new `hoNoReadChunked` flag, and then just tunnel the raw data from `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` directly to the client, such as by using a `TIdTCPStream` with `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteStream()`.

[New TIdHTTP flags and OnChunkReceived event](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/ChangeLog/20160110.aspx)

Comment: I cannot help but admire your commitment, Remy!

Comment: Remy, when I try to download file the Headers.Values['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'. And at line Client.IOHandler.ReadStream(Strm, -1, True); raises exception 10053. Do you can help me to fix this error?

Comment: The second example is acting as a proxy to forward data from another server.  If the `Content-Type` is `application/octet-stream` then that is what the other server is actually reporting. As for the 10053 error, that is normal behavior. The `AReadUntilDisconnect` parameter is set to True, and 10053 is `WSAECONNABORTED` which is one of several possible error codes during a disconnect. `ReadStream()` does not currently handle 10053 as a disconnect (that is a TODO item), so you will have to handle it manually. I updated my example to show that.

Comment: Because `AResponseInfo.WriteHeader` add to the header `Content-Length: 0` the connection of some players and browsers is breaks with exception 10053. You need instead `AResponseInfo.WriteHeader` use `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(...)` to send headers.

Comment: If you bypass `WriteHeader()`, you need to manually set `AResponseInfo.HeaderHasBeenWritten=true` to prevent `TIdHTTPServer` from calling `WriteHeader()` when `OnCommandGet` exits.

Comment: 3rd solution is amazing But you cannot seek video front back.How this can be done?

Comment: @vlad_n "*`AResponseInfo.WriteHeader` add to the header `Content-Length: 0`*" - it does that only if 1) `AResponseInfo.ContentLength = -1`, and 2) `AResponseInfo.TransferEncoding` is `''` or `'identity'`, and 3) `ARequestInfo.CommandType` is `hcHEAD` or `AResponseInfo.ResponseNo` is `1xx`, `204`, or `304`. Since `AResponseInfo.TransferEncoding` would be `'chunked'` in this case, #2 would be False, and so `WriteHeader()` should not be sending `Content-Length: 0`