# How to return a contentstream in Indy TIdHttpServer from a pipe

Tags: delphi, stream, pipe, indy, httpserver

I have a situation using TIdHttpServer in Delphi where the content can be fairly slow to generate.
I've tried creating pipes and returning a THandleStream as the ContentStream in TIdHTTPResponseInfo object, but Indy does not like to deal with a stream where the length is not known ahead of time.

Basically, it returns all the content written at the time of returning from the OnCommandGet.
Is there a convenient way to tell Indy that this is a stream of indeterminate size and to just keep reading until it gets an actual EOF?

I can read everything into a memorystream and that works, but I'm worried about timeouts, and it does seem to remove the benefits of working with streams in the first place.

Or is there a better component I should be using?

I am using this as a local REST server.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27694432/2292722) for a kind of similar question might give you ideas.

Comment: Tom is right. If you don't know the content length ahead of time, and/or don't have access to all of the content data at one time, then you must send the content in chunked format. Which `TIdHTTPServer` does not natively support, but does allow to do it manually. Just make sure the client is sending an HTTP 1.1 request, as HTTP 1.0 does not support chunking, but all HTTP 1.1 clients are required to support it

Comment: That works. Thanks! (If you put that as an answer, I will upvote it...)