# Indy MappedTCPPort headers

Tags: delphi, indy

I want to make a request on url http://127.0.0.1:8080 
I am using a TidMappedPortTCP component (indy 10)
On execute i have the follow code

```
procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var MyHeaders:Tstringlist;
begin

try
   MyHeaders:=Tstringlist.Create;

TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).NetData:=ToBytes('');
MyHeaders.clear;
MyHeaders.add('GET /Myfile.mp4 HTTP/1.1');
MyHeaders.add('Accept-Encoding:identity;q=1, *;q=0');
MyHeaders.add('Connection:keep-alive');
MyHeaders.add('Accept:*/*');
MyHeaders.add('Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9');
MyHeaders.add('Host:'+'112.32.12.115');
MyHeaders.add('Referer: MyappName');
MyHeaders.add('User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36');
//MyHeaders.add(''); Do i need also this?
TIdMappedPortContext(AContext).NetData:=ToBytes(MyHeaders.text);

finally
    MyHeaders.Free;
end;

end;
```

I Dont know what i am doing Wrong but the headers are send out without Crlf ( #13#10). is this Way the corect way to Overwrite my Request headers?

Comment: The `TStringList.Text` property uses platform-appropriate line breaks by default. But HTTP requires CRLF, so set `MyHeaders.LineBreak := #13#10;` However, `TIdMappedPortTCP` is not a good choice for this situation in general. You really should be using `TIdHTTPProxyServer` instead. In its `OnHTTPBeforeCommand` event, you can customize the `Command`, `Target`, and `Headers` of the provided `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext` as needed.

Comment: remy can you give me a simple example with idhttpProxyserver. All i want to do is to pass My one headers to an mp4. After that i dont want to touch anyting. Thanks

Comment: Well TIdHTTPProxyServer is not an Option Because my app is on android device and i cannot change TwebBrowser Proxy settings ( i dont know how and if is possible) so the problem with tidMappedtcpport is that onExecute the netdata contains the headers and more data and as you have suggest in other posts i need to create my ownbuffer and extract the headers from my buffer and leave the other data untuched correct?

Comment: in that case, I suggest using `TIdHTTPServer` and `TIdHTTP` instead. Let `TIdHTTPServer` buffer and parse the request for you. In its `OnCommandGet` event, alter and forward that info to `TIdHTTP`, let it download the MP4, which you can then send back to the client. I DO NOT recommend `TIdMappedPortTCP` for this scenario. HTTP is not a trivial protocol, you would have to implement a full HTTP parser inside your `OnExecute` handler, and be sure to handle that across multiple firings of the event, since it has no concept of message boundaries. That is a lot of work for a minimal gain.

Comment: the problem is that i want to stream the mp4 and not download it.Thanks any way i change my question to show to you what i want .

Comment: You can do streaming with `TIdHTTPServer` and `TIdHTTP`, it just takes a little bit of extra work to hook them up together. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27694432/65863) I posted a few years ago on that very topic.

Comment: I rolled back your question, as you *completely* changed it to something else. If you have a *different* question, post it *separately* as a new question.

Comment: your code is awesome it is play fine on windows when you call the url from chrome.Both examples #2 and #3 update example are working fine.But when i try to request the page from embed webbroswer in android i get error #104 with the exactly same code.Does your code works on firemonkey too? or i need to change something?