# Delphi Indy HTTPServer: Write text in Chunks possible?

Tags: csv, http, delphi, indy, indy10

Is it possible to send big amounts of text (csv database export) through an Indy HTTP Server in chunks to a requesting client to avoid hitting memory restrictions?

I am implementing a REST interface in an application server written in Delphi 10.4.2 as I can not expose the database connection for several reasons that are not negotiable.

The data will be consumed by statisticans using R.

As the amount of data can grow up to a GB, I have no good feeling filling a string and writing it to the connection.

Comment: If the response data is directed to a file stream on client side, the 1 GB data size will not affect the client's RAM usage. Indy HTTP Clients support this file-stream based response processing.

Comment: Thanks. Remys Code behind the link above should do the Job. I will write the query results to a file and send that in chunks. I hope R can handle that...

Comment: @mjn You are correct that the `chunked` transfer encoding is needed, however the link you provided has nothing to do with that encoding. Perhaps you meant [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27694432/65863) instead?

Comment: @MichaSchumann The answer mjn linked to is for handling HTTP requests utilizing the `Range` request header. That has nothing to do with what you are asking for. If you want to send large amounts of data in chunks, using `TIdHTTPRangeStream` is the wrong way to go. What you are looking for is the ['chunked' transfer encoding](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-3.6.1) in HTTP 1.1 and later, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27694432/65863).

Comment: Thanks for that info.

Comment: @Remy: I use TMS Sparkle that itself uses Indy HTTP server but unfortunately does not expose all Indy properties. Currently zipping the CSV seems to fit for the amount of data. But I will try to do clean HTTP chunking.

Answer (score 0):

@MichaSchumann,
Modern Internet Browser's use often "gzip"ed data that comes from an Apache2.4 WebServer (for Windows 10 Version - see XAMPP). The Browser commonly depack the data, and display the contents based on the file, and the magic content/type(s) (this can be text (html) or binary (pictures).

Indy 9 is sending there packets one to one. This means, the data is "not" secured, and "not" packed before sending.
So, You could be "gzip" Your CSV file (csv files consists commonly of ASCII-Text, which can be quick pack to a binary file that is a mount huge smaller in size, and the transmitting of the data stream does quicker on the stage (if You thinking over the time, what a 1 GiByte file need on time !

Note: you should be send a header for each chunck.
In this header, You save the relevant informations about the size of the actual transmitted chunk, and the position.

So, You can implement Your own FTP-Server that is remember his "position" state.
This is useful when the Connection breaks.
Normal (old FTP-Servers) have the cons that they need the first position of the first chunk of each broken Connection. This means: You have always send the file from 0 .. size.

Feel free to ask other question, I am open, You are welcome.

Comment: Thanks. Due to time constraints I currently zip the csv files before transfer and transfer this zip file. I discovered a limit of about 700 MB for the ZIP file and this contains about several GB CSV data that should fit.